# Getting error while uploading app on Windows Phone Store

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, app-store, manifest

**UPDATE 1**

Here's content of AppManifest.xaml

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" EntryPointAssembly="TurnMeOff" EntryPointType="TurnMeOff.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="TurnMeOff" Source="TurnMeOff.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui" Source="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

I am getting "2001: There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xml. Remove one of the files and then try again." while uploading XAP on the store.  According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206735(v=vs.105).aspx) I need to rebuild the app if it doesn't work I need to manually remove the duplicate AppManifest.xml, but my XAP is not having duplicate AppManifest.xml. Why I am not able to upload the app?

The XAP structure is like given below.

[image]

Comment: the content of AppManifest.xaml is invalid, not the content of .xap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. When anybody uses Microsoft Ad SDK, the manifest file references the DLL twice. See the code below. So to solve the problem open your XAP file in WinRAR or WinZip. Extract AppManifest.xaml and remove the duplicate DLL entries. After that add updated AppManifest.xaml into XAP.

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" EntryPointAssembly="TurnMeOff" EntryPointType="TurnMeOff.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="TurnMeOff" Source="TurnMeOff.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <!-- BELOW IS DUPLICATE OF ABOVE -->
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui" Source="microsoft.advertising.mobile.ui.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll" />
    <!-- BELOW IS DUPLICATE OF SECOND ONE -->
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```