# There are duplicate files in appmanifest.xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am in the final steps to put on the market an application and I have the error 2001: There are duplicate files in appmanifest.xml

This is what my appmanifest.xaml looks like:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" EntryPointAssembly="Smite" EntryPointType="Smite.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
    <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Smite" Source="Smite.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks" Source="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Source="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Phone" Source="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Phone.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="MyToolkit" Source="MyToolkit.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="MyToolkit.Extended" Source="MyToolkit.Extended.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll" />
    </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

and this is what my appmanifest.xml looks like:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Deployment.Parts>
    </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

I have tried to build, rebuild as Debug and Release, I have tried to delete the appmanifest.xaml, always the same error (appears twice).

If anybody know why I've this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187323/getting-error-while-uploading-app-on-windows-phone-store

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, I'll try what you did.

Comment: It's okay Xyroid, it worked. Create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem, check out my answer [Getting error while uploading app on Windows Phone Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187323/getting-error-while-uploading-app-on-windows-phone-store)

Microsoft should correct the bug in either SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Two assemblies are listed twice in your file:

```
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
```

Removing the duplicates may solve the issue:

```
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
<AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
```

Comment: I have tried this, but It doesn't. Moreover, If I delete'em and rebuild the solution, those two lines reappears

Comment: what is interesting to notice is that I have Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll and Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll but I have too Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.xml and Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.xml

Maybe it's the reason why it generates duplicates?